# Add an additional dc field to simpe or brief item view in DSpace 7.6

Tags: dspace

I intend to add an additional dc field, so it displays in the brief and extended item view. I need to include an alternative link to fulltext stored in a separate dc field.

I can't figure out which angular component to adjust to achieve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

archives point to: untyped-item.component. Will dig archive first!